# NgFor grid System

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have an array of [key:strings] that i show like this:

```
item1 item2 item3
item4 item5 item6
item7 item8 item9
```

however I have to add a dividing line, to print the results like this:

```
item1 item2 item3
----------------
item4 item5 item6
----------------
item7 item8 item9
```

This is a snippet of the code responsible for the layout

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 mb-5" *ngFor="let detail of details | keyvalue:originalOrder;">
      <b>{{detail.key }}</b>:{{ detail.value }}
    </div>
</div>
```

With this solution adding a line obviously produce this result:

```
item1  item2  item3
-----  -----  ----
item4  item5  item6
-----  -----  ----
item7  item8  item9
```

How can I adapt the code to render a dividing line in a new row when I reach the end of column?

Comment: use one more *ngFor in the class="row" div as well.

and use ngClass="lastrow ? 'row' : 'underlinedrow'"

Comment: But what should I iterate in the row div? An index?

Comment: without iterate how will you move to next rows? or else you do not need to have row level ngFor, you break to the new row on every 3rd detail object

Comment: That's basically what I'm asking. The ngFor that renders the column seems correct, it's the external one that I can't figure what I should iterate to write a new row.